# CSS how to deal with a lot of sprite without having to create a new css class

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I have a list of image (around 30) and I want to create CSS sprite so that they are colored when hovered. The images all have the same size. The problem is that if I just want to have one css class, I have to put the background-image on the inline html like this :

CSS:

```
.sprite{
    background-position: 0 0;
    width: 185px;
    height: 100px;
}

.sprite:hover{
    background-position: 185px 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="sprite" style="background: url('image1');">
<div class="sprite" style="background: url('image2');">
<div class="sprite" style="background: url('image3');">
...
```

And it does not work. I only manage to do the sprite if I put the background image on the css but if I do this, I would have to create as many CSS classes as I have images which is not elegant at all. Do you have a better idea? (PS: I'm using Less CSS)

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? You don't see any image at all?

Comment: Well having a css class makes more sense than cluttering the html with inline styles. The concept of sprite is to have a single image and used background position to call it.Looking at your code- How many sprites do you have? Does all the images have the same position? If you can make a jsfiddle or codepen example, maybe we can debug your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is that you overwrite all background attributes inline (incl. -position); use:

```
style="background-image: url('image1');"
```

Answer (score 1):

Often sprites are used for icons, then people would create one `.icon` class and 'extend' it by another class like `.icon.facebook`. The `.icon` class contains all the dimensions and other default settings for the icon. The extended class does the customization of the icon.

```
.icon {
  width: ...;
  height: ...;
  display: inline-block;
  background: transparent url(...) no-repeat;
}
.icon.facebook {
  background-position: ...px ...px;
}
.icon.facebook:hover {
  // color version
  background-position: ...px ...px;
}
```

Comment: @fast "The extended class does the customization of the icon." which allows the `bacground-image` to be overriden.